Why do lipid-rich foods release more energy during combustion than simple sugars?
We recently did a science experiment in class in which a marshmallow and a Cheeto were burned at separate times and the amount of energy they released into the environment was measured (burning item was placed under a can of water and the temperature increase of the water was observed). It turned out that the Cheeto released much more energy than the marshmallow, and my teacher explained it was because of the high energy density of lipids as compared to carbohydrates. However, I don't exactly understand how this works. How do these food items release energy?
AI said:

Stronger bond enthalpy for Cheetos causes more energy to be released when more stable bonds are formed.

This doesn't make any sense to me and I'm not really sure how accurate it is, for AI hallucination happens often.
Basically, I was just wondering why the chemical composition of Cheetos make them release more energy during combustion than marshmallows in terms of bonds breaking and forming.
Thanks!

Think of it this way. Lipids are basically just С and H. Carbs contain O, lots of it. They are already halfway oxidized.

This question is similar to: Energy in molecules. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also, marshmallows have much more moisture than Cheetos. Unless the two foods were dehydrated to the same moisture content, it's a false comparison. It's like comparing apples and oranges: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges

Perhaps the easiest explanation is that per carbon atom in fats vs. carbohydrates you need more oxygen to oxidize fats to carbon dioxide compared to oxygen needed to oxidize carbohydrates to carbon dioxide. The bonds broken in dioxygen are weak compared to the carbon-oxygen and the hydrogen-oxygen bonds in the products. The more oxygen a combustion reaction uses, the more exothermic it is.
Carbon in a fat:
$$\ce{-CH2 - + 3/2 O2 -> CO2 + H2O}$$
Carbon in a sugar:
$$\ce{-CH(OH) - + O2 -> CO2 + H2O}$$
For the experiment, you did not say whether you compared the same mass or the same volume of food, and whether you took care that you had a complete reaction.

The teacher didn't make these specific details about the experiment clear to us, so I'm not entirely sure. Also, is dioxygen part of the reactants?

Yes, combustion and cellular respiration both require oxygen. Take a deep breath…

So more dioxygen in the reactants creates stronger carbon-oxygen and hydrogen-oxygen bonds in the products, which releases more energy?

@user386598 At sugars, part of the stronger  C=O and O-H bonds (than C-H and C-O ) are already pre-created ( and part of energy pre-released). Additionally, sugars carry extra oxygen weight with them. You can imagine analogy fat = pure coal, sugar = coal premixed with coal ash.
